# User Input Service's Input Began not firing

Tags: lua, roblox

I am working with User Input Service to make a snake game within Roblox, and the event, Input Began, is not firing.  I even copied code from the official Roblox website to teach how to script, and nothing happened. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Are you using a Script or a LocalScript? Where is the code located?

Comment: @kylaaa I had tried both, but I will try again just to see if that is the issue
Edit: I have tried both again and still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UserInputService](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/UserInputService) only works in [LocalScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/LocalScript), and according to the docs :

> A LocalScript will only run Lua code if it is a descendant of one of the following objects:
>
> - A Player’s Backpack, such as a child of a Tool
> - A Player’s character model
> - A Player’s PlayerGui
> - A Player’s PlayerScripts.
> - The ReplicatedFirst service

Double check that your LocalScript is in one of those locations and that it is not Disabled.

Comment: thank you it works now, but shouldn't it work inside Replicated Storage also?

Comment: No, ReplicatedStorage just a storage location, same with ServerStorage. You can put scripts there but they won't fire